# Rust lettre library does not send emails on windows

Tags: linux, windows, rust, rust-cargo

I'm developing a Rust script that monitors a folder for new files and when it detects them it sends them to an api and then sends them by mail. Everything is fine so far, I have tested and compiled it in Linux and it works perfectly, but when I run it in Windows 10 it does not send the email but if it uploads it to the api without problems, it should be noted that I have created a project from windows and I have put the same code. In windows I already configured the firewall to allow connections and it still does not send the mail, the credentials and everything is the same.

main.rs

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use notify::{Watcher, RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Result, EventKind, Event};
use reqwest;

mod email_sender;

// Importa el módulo email_senders.rs
use dotenv::dotenv;
// Importa la biblioteca dotenv
use std::env;

fn load_sent_files() -> HashSet<String> {
    if let Ok(content) = fs::read_to_string("sent_files.txt") {
        content.lines().map(|line| line.to_string()).collect()
    } else {
        HashSet::new()
    }
}

fn save_sent_files(sent_files: &HashSet<String>) {
    let content: Vec<String> = sent_files.iter().cloned().collect();
    if let Err(e) = fs::write("sent_files.txt", content.join("\n")) {
        println!("Error al guardar los archivos enviados: {:?}", e);
    }
}

fn upload_file(file_path: &Path, sent_files: &mut HashSet<String>) {
    let file_name = file_path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string();

    if sent_files.contains(&file_name) {
        println!("Archivo {} ya ha sido enviado anteriormente.", file_name);
        return;
    }

    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/upload"; // Ajusta esto a la URL de tu API

    let form = reqwest::blocking::multipart::Form::new()
        .file("file", file_path)
        .unwrap(); // Puedes manejar este error de una mejor manera si lo deseas

    let response = client.post(url)
        .multipart(form)
        .send();

    match response {
        Ok(resp) => {
            if resp.status().is_success() {
                // Obtiene el cuerpo de la respuesta y lo muestra.
                let response_body = resp.text().unwrap_or_else(|_| String::from("Respuesta vacía"));
                println!("Respuesta del servidor: {}", response_body);
                println!("Archivo enviado con éxito: {}", file_name);

                // Agrega el nombre del archivo al conjunto de archivos enviados
                sent_files.insert(file_name.clone());
                save_sent_files(&sent_files);  // Guarda el conjunto actualizado en el archivo

                // Envía el archivo adjunto por correo electrónico
                let recipient_email = env::var("RECIPIENT_EMAIL").expect("RECIPIENT_EMAIL not set");
                if let Err(e) = email_sender::send_email_with_attachment(file_path, &recipient_email,&file_name) {
                    println!("Error al enviar el correo electrónico: {:?}", e);
                }
            } else {
                println!("Error al enviar el archivo: {:?}", resp.text().unwrap_or_else(|_| String::from("Error desconocido")));
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error en la solicitud: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    println!("Monitor de carpeta iniciado.");
    // Carga las variables de entorno desde el archivo .env
    dotenv().ok();

    let mut sent_files = load_sent_files();  // Carga el conjunto de archivos enviados al iniciar

    let mut watcher: RecommendedWatcher = notify::recommended_watcher(move |res: Result<Event>| {
        match res {
            Ok(event) => {
                if let EventKind::Create(_) = event.kind {
                    let file_path = &event.paths[0];
                    println!("Archivo nuevo detectado: {:?}", file_path);
                    upload_file(file_path, &mut sent_files); // Pasa el conjunto a la función upload_file
                }
            }
            Err(e) => println!("Error al monitorear: {:?}", e),
        }
    })?;
    let folder_path = env::var("FOLDER_PATH").expect("FOLDER_PATH not set");
    watcher.watch(Path::new(&folder_path), RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;
    std::thread::park();
    Ok(())
}
```

email_sender.rs

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::error::Error;
use lettre::message::{header, Message};
use lettre::message::{header::ContentType, MultiPart, SinglePart, Attachment};
use lettre::transport::smtp::authentication::Credentials;
use lettre::{SmtpTransport, Transport};
use anyhow::Result;
use std::{fs, env};

pub fn send_email_with_attachment(file_path: &Path, recipient_email: &str, file_name: &str) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_name = file_name.to_string();
    let file_content = fs::read(file_path)?;

    // Use the correct ContentType for MiniSEED files
    let content_type = ContentType::parse("application/vnd.fdsn.mseed").unwrap();

    // Create a single part for the attachment
    let attachment = Attachment::new(file_name.clone()).body(file_content, content_type);

    let message = String::from("Envio MSeed");

    let email = Message::builder()
        .from("mi_email@gmail.com".parse().unwrap())
        .to(recipient_email.parse().unwrap())
        .subject("Envio Miniseed")
        .multipart(
            MultiPart::mixed()
                .singlepart(
                    SinglePart::builder()
                        .header(header::ContentType::TEXT_PLAIN)
                        .body(message), 
                )
                .singlepart(attachment),
        )
        .unwrap();

    let smtp_username = env::var("SMTP_USERNAME").expect("SMTP_USERNAME not set");
    let smtp_password = env::var("SMTP_PASSWORD").expect("SMTP_PASSWORD not set");
    let smtp_host = env::var("SMTP_HOST").expect("SMTP_HOST not set");

    let creds = Credentials::new(smtp_username, smtp_password);

    // Open a remote connection to gmail
    let mailer = SmtpTransport::relay(&smtp_host)?
        .credentials(creds)
        .build();

    // Send the email
    match mailer.send(&email) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(println!("Correo enviado exitosamente!")),
        Err(e) => panic!("Error al enviar correo: {:?}", e),
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
notify = { version = "6.0.1", features = ["serde"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json", "blocking", "multipart"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
log = "0.4.19"
lettre = "0.10"
mime = "0.3.17"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
anyhow = "1.0.57"
```

In windows I already configured the firewall to allow connections and it still does not send the mail, the credentials and everything is the same.
There is an example of that library with version 0.10 and it works on windows but I create my own code with the library and that's when it doesn't send.

Image:
https://imgur.com/a/9fDCgSA

Comment: How do you know it's not sending the email? Maybe you're just not receiving it, due to spam filtering or something.

Comment: Why in linux if it sends it and gives me the message that the mail was sent successfully. And if I receive it without problems
I am using the same credentials and data.

Comment: Please provide the exact error you got instead of just "does not work".

Comment: It just doesn't throw an error. It gets stuck on line 49 of email_sender.rs:

     match mailer.send(&email) {
         Ok(_) => Ok(println!("Mail sent successfully!")),
         Err(e) => panic!("Error sending mail: {:?}", e),
     }
And nothing else happens in the console...

Comment: I was debugging the code up to line 49 of the email_sender.rs, when I take the next step after the match mailer.send(&email) nothing else happens, it freezes, it doesn't send any error or it stops, it doesn't do anything.This only happens in windows, in linux I do the same and if it gives me an answer.

Comment: Have you verified that the target host (environment SMTP_HOST) and port (465) is reachable from the windows system? Maybe it hangs while trying to connect to a host which is not reachable.

Comment: The curious thing is that this test code does work well in windows and sends the mail without problems and makes the same connection with the same gmail smtp: https://pastebin.com/pEhY5K0G

Answer (score 0):

Your default feature set for lettre includes `native-tls` feature that enables you to use `SmtpTransport::relay` constructor.

I've checked the docs and it says `native-tls` feature uses `schannel` on Windows. Might be a needed dependency for your script to work